# Rekey a Kryptonite lock outside North America

Tags: lock, security

Kryptonite offer a re-keying service in North America for those who failed to register their keys and have since lost all of them.  I'm in Europe, and such a service is not offered here, I'm wondering if any good locksmith would be able to offer such a service or if Kryptonite use proprietary technology that wouldn't allow for general locksmiths to re-key.

The lock I have that needs a key for is the Evolution Series 4

Comment: You may end up paying as much to have the lock re-keyed as it would cost for a new lock.

Comment: Ask a locksmith.

Comment: Locksmiths very rarely have the equipment to deal with bike locks. I have talked to a number of ABUS-branded locksmiths and none could touch an ABUS bike lock (in Australia). The tools are different.

Comment: The evolution series 4 isn't exactly very expensive in the US -- the rekey fee + shipping is about as much as the lock.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Kryptonite doesn't actually "rekey" the lock but instead gives you an entirely new lock and keys, in roughly the same series type as the one you sent in.

In that case, I think the best solution would be to find someone going back to the USA and sell the lock to them for (price of new lock in that series ) * (whatever hassle percentage discount you think appropriate) - $20 - $8.

You'd essentially be selling that person a new lock after they send it in: the $20  "rekey" fee includes shipping back to the customer in the domestic states and the extra $8 is because that person will need to ship the old lock back to  Kryptonite in the first place.

> Given that a new Evo 4 is around US$70 - you could sell the dead lock
>   to someone going back to the USA for $20. They could send it in for +$20+$8 = $48 and get a
>   new lock. The math isn't very good for the Evo 4 -- much better for
>   the expensive NY series locks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a shipping service from the US to re-ship the new keys to you, but I'm assuming that you have to send the lock in, and have them ship it back ? If that's the case, a new lock would probably be cheaper.